# Hide gridview cell (value) base on other cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a Gridview with ItemTemplate using some Labels and 3 Button (Deactivate, Delete and Edit) as seen in picture below:

[image]

I want to hide these buttons from some users base on their username (Label UserName on Gridview), for example:

- `If UserName == "some string"` then **hide** the **Deactivate, Delete** and **Edit** buttons

How do I do this in code behind `RowDataBound` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by using Gridview RowDataBound event you can do that

```
protected void grd1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
        Label lbl=e.Row.FindControl("your cotrol Id")as Label;
       if(lbl!=null && lbl.Text.Trim()=="some string")
       {
           e.Row.FindControl("deactivate btn Id").Visible = false;
           e.Row.FindControl("delete btn Id").Visible = false;
           e.Row.FindControl("edit btn Id").Visible = false;
       }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the row data by column index, in the RowDataBound event you need to check if its a data row, not a header or footer..etc

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  if(e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "some string")
  {
    Button delete = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("control id to hide");
    delete.Visisble = false;
  }
}
```